# CSS/CSS3 background auto increase with content

Tags: html, css

how can i make my backgrounds (eg. header bg or footer bg) to auto expand horizontally with the content i put on any of the main content areas in my code? .. :) any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that I can think of:

1. Dynamically create your CSS stylesheet.  Doing this will allow you to change the sizes of the image accordingly. *This is overkill and probably too involved for what you need.*
2. Set the width to be 100% (`width: 100%`).  This will fill the entire area regardless of its size. *This works great in most instances, and might be useful for you.*
3. Create an instance of a repeating background and repeat it horizontally (`repeat-x`).  *I think that this is probably the best solution for you as it doesn't distort the background like when stretched as described above.*